# How do you maintain a constant load on the cpu?

Tags: setcpu

I am looking at my phone with a thermal camera to watch the external heat distribution as I attempt to hold it at a constant high load.

What I need to do is hold the CPU at a constant load over the span of about 30 mins, I have achieved this with relative success using the two "burner" apps available on google play. I paired this with SetCPU to max out the allowable core frequencies.

I have used HWMonitor PRO to view the temp sensor values and record them on my PC.

Does anyone know if there is an app available that applies a repeatably constant load or how one would begin to do so through programming? The main issue I am finding is that the burner apps will shut down after a certain time (or temperature) and don't feel very consistent.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you want the app to not stop, just launch a thread (to prevent hanging) that does some complex calculation in a `while`-loop. Nothing else to add to your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install a terminal emulator and try the following:

dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/null

or

dd if=/dev/random of=/dev/null

It will write random values to the nirvana, should cause a constant load. But since you typically have a lot of different processes on your phone running, it is hard to assure some processes don't wake up and cause load interruptions. Therefore, switch the phone to flight mode, disable all other connections like wifi/bluetooth/nfc etc. and try to shut down as many services as you can. But still, e.g. the garbage collector could run at unexpected times. Android is just not a realtime OS, but for the measurement you are probably attempting it should be sufficient.

And in case your device has several cores: Open more tabs in the emulator and run more dd processes.

Comment: I'm just curious if the *CPU* is doing much work there? It seems the memory controller has more to do. Generating random numbers is no significant work for a modern CPU.

Comment: Yes but at least the load should be pretty constant. To get higher load, you should probably also exercise the GPU as well. I would recommend gears/glxgears for this: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jeffboody.GearsES2eclair

Comment: That's true. The GPU can stress the device as well. I don't know how hot it will get but it should be quite hot.

Comment: Looking forward to the feedback of the OP then.

Comment: Thank you kuleszdl for your answer, I have tried what you mentioned and it appears to be working! The CPU utilization isn't maxed (sitting at around 30-50%) but the temps definitely increment with each process addition. @GiantTree is likely correct. The idea is more about temperature than cpu utilization so this is probably going to be enough. Does wifi/bluetooth/cellular add any heat with their modules?, I am figuring it is negligible in comparison to the CPU/GPU.

Comment: I don't know any other hardware other that CPU/GPU that generates much heat. WiFi shouldn't do it because it would lose connectivity (technical stuff on how WiFi works), Bluetooth as well and cellular network is the same. They don't generate heat because they are designed to use a minimum amount of power so that it would only drain your battery but not generate any additional heat. CPU and GPU are the main heat producers together with the battery itself.

Comment: Well I assume it really depends how these components are implemented in hardware. In many SoCs, the modem is located in the same chip as the CPU while in some it is on a separate chip. My experience with designs which use a separated modem is that if you use the modem a lot, it generates a lot of heat even if CPU usage is low. Maybe start a process which fetches some big file from your local network or a remote location and writes it to /dev/null, similar to the dd process above and check if this causes more heat.